# Why can't Ansible find an executable that's in the system path?

Tags: windows, ansible, 7zip

Ansible v2.11
Target: Windows 2012 Server

I'm trying to unzip a file using the `C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe` utility, and that folder is in the system path. I can't use `win_unzip` because of long file names. However I get this?

```
- name: "Unzip exa-web {{ exa_web_zip }}"
  win_command:
    7z x {{ remote_dir }}/{{ exa_web_zip }} -o{{ exa_web_dir }}

TASK [exa-web : Unzip exa-web exa-web-development-b7cf4eee3c-20210930_1700-win64.zip] ***
fatal: [172.16.100.31]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "7z x C:\\temp/exa-web-development-b7cf4eee3c-20210930_1700-win64.zip -oC:\\Viztek\\EXA\\web", "msg": "Exception calling \"SearchPath\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"Could not find file '7z.exe'.\"", "rc": 2}
```

I even added this task just to ensure that is is in the system path, to no avail.

```
- name: Add to system path
  win_path:
    elements:
      - "C:\\Program Filse\\7-zip"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `Filse` --> `Files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a common parameter you should use, it is called `chdir`. Then ansible should find the executable:

```
- name: "Unzip exa-web {{ exa_web_zip }}"
  win_command:
    7z x {{ remote_dir }}/{{ exa_web_zip }} -o{{ exa_web_dir }}
  args:
    chdir: 'C:\Program Filse\7-zip'
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes the issue. But I still wonder why Ansible can't fine the `7z` utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your environment variables in `.profile` and then use

```
ansible all -m shell -a '. /etc/profile;<command>' -b
```

Replace `<command>` with whatever you are trying to do.